# Emacs - How to wrap selection in org-mode source code block?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a bunch of elisp and other code with some notes i wanted to reformat to be more organized, and i found that having to type

```lisp
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp ... #+END_SRC
```

all the time around what i want, is taking a bit longer than expected...

So what i wanted to do instead is to wrap/or put the selected content (with C-space) and put it in a template source code block for org-mode (in my case it's mostly elisp code, but i plan to use it for other things maybe)

How could i do this in emacs or in elisp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [wrap-region](https://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region.el). It will allow you to define what type of string you want to wrap around a selection.

Put this in your `init.el` and evaluate it.

```lisp
(wrap-region-global-mode t)
(wrap-region-add-wrapper "#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp\n" "#+END_SRC" "#" 'org-mode)
```

Then, while you are editing your `org` files, you can select a block of text and type `#`, which will wrap it with your string. You can change the `#` to another character that will do the wrapping.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new [templating mechanism](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html#Structure-Templates) in recent Org mode (>= 9.0 IIRC) that allows you tor wrap a region in a block: after selecting the region in the usual manner, you say `C-c C-, s`. You still have to type the `emacs-lisp` part though. That's the disadvantage. The advantage is that it is general enough to allow you to wrap a region in any kind of block. In your case, I think the disadvantage outweighs the advantage, so I would go with the `wrap-region` method in the other answer, but this one is good to know as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature in org-mode to do exactly that. It's like a snippet of some sort where you enter `<el`and hit TAB, the < char is here to say we're gonna use a template and the el part tells which template to use. But of course, you have to configure it first.

For that, you can just add this to an org-mode file or to your init.el file :

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp

;; This is needed as of Org 9.2
(require 'org-tempo)

(add-to-list `org-structure-template-alist `("sh" . "src shell"))
(add-to-list `org-structure-template-alist `("el" . "src emacs-lisp"))
(add-to-list `org-structure-template-alist `("py" . "src python"))

#+end_src
```

There a bunch of way to use this, it's actually more useful than just use it as a template, you can go check the documentation [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/index.html).

Comment: didn't know about `org-tempo`. Nice stuff, thanks :D

Comment: It's not really org-tempo that does that. It's needed for some reason, but it's really a feature of org that has built-in templates for code blocks.

Comment: yeah, noticed after the fact. Still a nice alternative, thank you